# Can jQuery be used to copy text on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, jquery-events

I am trying to get jQuery to copy an element's title attribute when it is clicked, but I think I'm having a problem with event bubbling.

I can do this easily enough with straight JS, but I'm trying to understand how to do this with jQuery.

Here is my code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="copy" title="actual text to be copied">Hello world.</p>

    <script>
    $('document').ready(function(){

      $(".copy").on({
        click: function(e) {
          document.execCommand("copy");
        },
        copy: function(event) {
          if (event.originalEvent.clipboardData) {
            // allegedly copies the text to the clipboard
            event.originalEvent.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", $(this)[0].title);
            // show us what was copied.
            alert(event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("text"));
          }
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`event.clipboardData` doesn't exist, but `event.originalEvent.clipboardData`, so I'm working with that.

But I think the problem is that `event.originalEvent.clipboardData` is not actually the clipboard. But jQuery doesn't seem to expose that part of the API to it's own `event`.

Do I make jQuery apply it to the actual event rather than to `originalEvent`? If yes, then how so?

Here's a jsbin: https://jsbin.com/borumexuga/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You could create a temp input and place the text there, run execCommand('copy'), then remove the temp element.

Comment: That's so "unclean" to me. I'm hoping there's a more precise way to do this than using a workaround.

Comment: It seems like Luis has a good solution. I didn't think about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert `event.preventDefault();` inside the if.

https://jsbin.com/guwowomece/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Luis to the rescue! Thank you sir, I learned something today.